# Modifying the Page Title with PHP after the fact

Tags: php, dom

I would like to be able to change the page title with PHP. Now before you all answer with

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

I have a limitations... I am developing a plugin where my PHP is only inserted into the body of the page. Therefore `<title>` has already been defined and I would like to change it. Any ideas?

Edit: I am aware that this can be easily done with javascript. However, for SEO purposes I do not want to. I would like the actual contents of the `<title>` tag to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a JavaScript snippet, that changes the title. As the if your PHP code is inserted, the header part is already streamed, so you have no way of getting that back.

Comment: I guess that this is the answer... sad.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    document.title = '<?=$title;?>';
</script>
```

Comment: I would prefer to use pure PHP for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need echo some JavaScript that will change the title in-browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>document.title = '<?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($title); ?>';</script>
```

works only for js-enabled browser

Comment: Why the mysql_real_escape_string()?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify it using javascript:

```
window.status="YourNewTitle";
```

Thus you can try to insert your code within a `<script>` tag and beg your browser to execute it when it's loaded.